# Why is gmail (G Suite) bot visiting the links I click on?

Tags: privacy, google

We send to our staff notification emails with links to "private" pages on our website. These pages are password protected, we log the access and get notifications when accessed from new ip ranges.

To read these emails, our staff use G Suite.

We have noticed that every time someone clic on a link, a Google bot is requesting the same url a few seconds *later*.

Do you know why exactly? Are they storing the data?

Comment: I have observed this today. It caused glitch in my system and now I'll have to protect against that. In fact one of M$ messager was doing the same. Their excuse was that they were searching for links with viruses, analysing and suppressing them. But I haven't asked for that.